# How to Open "App Notifications" Screen in settings By Intent (Screen Shot Attached)

Tags: android, android-intent, android-pendingintent, android-settings

[image]

I have tried many intents from class android.provider.settings but not able to open this Screen Directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the activity's package name and class name from the manifest.xml of Settings,so you can do it like this :

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName("com.android.settings","com.android.settings.Settings$NotificationAppListActivity");
intent.setComponent(componentName);
startActivity(intent);
```

And I tested it on Anroid 8.1.0 nexus 6p.